# Emulator option is not showing in VS 2019 after system restart

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I have updated vs into VS2019 and also update sdk and installed one emulator. It was worked fine. But after system restart  the installed emulator is not showing in vs. Please help on this.

Comment: Please take a look Tools-Android-Android SDK Manager, whether you have installed Android sdk. then take a look Tools-Android-Android Device Manager, to start android emulator again.

Comment: installed latest sdk with the help of administrator. I am a non administrator user. The emulator was listed with his login.

Comment: You said that it works fine before machine restart, so I guess it may be a non-administrative problem.